# How to set header with two different colors for the left and right side

Tags: css

Header left and right side should display white and blue colors while body background-color grey.

White color for left side area with logo inside header and blue color for right one.

Using colorzilla, I've made background for the `container1` horizontally half blue for the right side. Then I included a couple pseudo elements for razor-blade effect. And when I set `background-color` for body I realized that the area with my logo inside header colored with body color.

I read about `linear-gradien`t but I was told that using it I'll face cross-browsing issues because even if you do it the way it should still there are a list of versions or even browsers that wouldn't understand it.

That's exactly where I find myself stuck. I need that all browsers and versions understood this code or as much as possible in this case. Please tell me how can I do that without using Colorzilla and `linear-gradient`.

```css
  @media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .container1 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: https://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#1e5799+44,1e5799+44,7db9e8+45,1e5799+45,7db9e8+46,7db9e8+46,7db9e8+46,7db9e8+46,7db9e8+46,7db9e8+46,1e5799+46,7db9e8+50,1e5799+50,1e5799+100&0+44,0+46,1+47 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0) 44%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0) 45%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0) 46%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 47%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 50%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 100%);
    /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0) 44%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0) 45%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0) 46%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 47%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 50%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 100%);
    /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0) 44%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0) 45%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0) 46%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 47%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 50%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 100%);
    /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#001e5799', endColorstr='#1e5799', GradientType=1);
    /* IE6-9 */
  }
  .logo {
    width: 250px;
  }
  header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0em 3.15em;
  }
  .cont {
    position: relative;
  }
  .cont::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 40em;
    height: 15rem;
    background: blue;
    bottom: -.8em;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  .cont::before {
    left: 42%;
    transform: skew(-30deg);
  }
  .cont::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 1.6em;
    height: 10rem;
    background: green;
    bottom: -.8em;
  }
  .cont::after {
    left: 38.9%;
    transform: skew(-30deg);
  }
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="cont">
    <header>
      <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="O-Credit logo" class="logo">

      <nav>
        <div id="menu-bar" class="hide-desk">
          <div class="menu" id="menu">
            <div id="bar1" class="bar"></div>
            <div id="bar2" class="bar"></div>
            <div id="bar3" class="bar"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <ul class="show-desk hide-mob" id="nav">
          <li id="exit" class="exit-btn close hide-desk">
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Обрати позику</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Компанії</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Види позик</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Блог</a></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

    </header>
  </div>
</div>
```

Left side of header with logo to show background white. Right side of the same header to show background blue. And set Body to show background grey everywhere but header.

Comment: If `linear-gradient` works for you, use it. https://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient It's really only IE6-9 that do not support it.

Answer (score 0):

```
.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0em 3.15em;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, blue 50%, red 50%)
}
```

Comment: Not exactly. Is there a chance to find some way to include old browsers and IE as well?